# Improving GeoServer rendering speed of rasters

Tags: raster, geoserver

I am running a GeoServer instance in docker and using that to render raster tiles but am finding the rendering to be very slow. I have tried adding the rasters to the Data Store as a single GeoTIFF, as an Image Mosaic from a dir of multiple rasters, and an Image Pyramid made from a raster with `gdal_retile.py`, but they all seem to be very slow. I have found that the size (GBs) of the file doesnt seem to affect the speed of rendering speed, but is more to do with the number of pixels in the raster, which makes sense. I am going to have multiple raster files which collectively will cover the whole of the UK and will total hundreds of GBs. My question is really suggestions on how to improve the rendering speed of rendering from Geoserver.

I am running on docker on an EC2 instance, so one solution is likely to be simply launch an EC2 instance with more resources. Is there anything else I can do? Perhaps a way to make Geoserver render with slightly less accuracy or preprocessing the rasters to make it easier for Geoserver. Or even using Postgres as a data source rather than the GeoTIFFs directly?

Comment: Have you read and applied the recommendations from the manual? Tiled and compressed the geotifs and added overviews

Comment: have you computed overviews/pyramids?

Comment: I do not know if anybody has made a proper benchmark in EC2 environment. Maybe it would require some special tricks. Study the results of https://www.slideshare.net/gatewaygeomatics.com/wms-performance-shootout-2011 and compare the speed that they had back then. Maybe you could also make a test with your own data on EC2 vs on local machine.

Comment: I have looked into Image Pyramids and tried that with no success, however I have not seen about overviews so I will start by looking into that. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Add tile cache. It will resolve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).